# Change title size on a barchart (lattice package) in R

Tags: r

All I want to do is change the size of the title on my barchart. You'd think it was easy but I can't seem to get it to work. Please help

```
barchart(b~n,data=EndoMinDataSet,groups=s, 
         scales=list(x=list(rot=0,cex=1.8),y=list(cex=1.8),main=list("My graph title",cex=2.8)),   
         key=list(space="right",
                  lines=list(col=c("purple","lightgreen"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=16),
                  text=list(c("On surveillance","Off surveillance"),cex=1.8)
         ))
```

Comment: Could you dput() your data, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure giving an answere without an reproducible example, but try to exclude `main=list("My graph title",cex=2.8)` from `scales`. For example:

```
barchart(b~n,data=EndoMinDataSet,groups=s, 
     scales=list(x=list(rot=0,cex=1.8),y=list(cex=1.8)),
     main=list("My graph title",cex=2.8),   
     key=list(space="right",
              lines=list(col=c("purple","lightgreen"), lty=c(2,2), lwd=16),
              text=list(c("On surveillance","Off surveillance"),cex=1.8)
     ))
```